# Reduce Method Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, reduce

Am getting false output for the below code. I know reduce concept in javascript. But the below I could not understand. Please help me with this.

```js
var numbers = [175, 50, 25];

var res = numbers.reduce(myFunc, []);

function myFunc(total, num) {
  return total.length > num.length;
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `reduce` passes in the result of the last execution as well as an item from the array you pass it (optionally, an initial 'last' value as you have specified in `[]`), but you are calling `length` in the array-item, which is a number

Comment: its not like reduce usage.its like a sorting array .i can't understand what you expect from this reduce

Comment: `num` is a number. Hence `num.length` becomes `undefined` and `total` is an empty array hence `total.length` will return `0` . So `0 > undefined` will return `false`. This is correct result.

Comment: @SudhirOjha - num.length will check the array length. In that case it returns length as 3. Then how come it return as undefined.

Comment: @Faruk No, it's never getting the entire array - you are getting a single value each time. First time you are calling `myFunc([], 175)`, then the result of that is passed in next time so `myFunc(false, 50)`, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Reduce function will not return the array to you it will reduce your array to a sigle value according to the operation perfom inside the function,

so in your example it will always return the false because there is blank array in param and you are comparing that array with `total` which is single number coming from `numbers` I think

Please go through the below link which will help you to understand `reduce()` function in a batter way,

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp